# VBA automatically run macro in excel, if cell value = current time?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a piece of vba code automatically when the time in a cell matches the current pc time.

Cell A2 is on sheet 1, cell A2 contains a time value of 19:00 for example

Here is my code:

This workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.OnTime TimeValue(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2").Value), "MyMacro"

End Sub
```

Module1:

```
Sub MyMacro()
MsgBox "Hey"
End Sub
```

For some reason this doesnt work, please can someone show me where i am going wrong? Thanks

Comment: What is ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2").Value

Comment: @Nathan_Sav please see updated question. Cell A2 contains 19:00 as time format

Comment: think you need to add seconds also, and perhaps it needs to be the text value rather than the value, as this will be a number??

Answer (score 1):

A Cell with a Time Serial formatted to display as a time is *already* in the correct format for `OnTime`, so just use

```
Application.OnTime ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2").Value, "MyMacro"
```

Comment: I tried this approach but for some reason it didn't seem to work (hence my more complicated but now deleted answer). I just tried it again and it does work. I must have had some sort of typo in my original test.